# node - use external js included in layout

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a js library that is generally included in the head section of a page, I've tried downloading / including it as a file in my app but it uses the window object and some other stuff that doesn't seem to work.

If I do this in the handlebars layout it works and the function:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://somelink.com/file.js"></script>
    <script>
        var client = file.someFunction();
        client.doSomething();
    </script>
</head>
```

it works, but I need to use that client object form inside my scripts, is there a way to import this normally?

Comment: What library are you trying to use?

Comment: It's the zendesk app framework (V2, I know there is a v1 github version but I need the new one). Here is the link: https://assets.zendesk.com/apps/sdk/2.0/zaf_sdk.js

Comment: Right, this looks like a front end script (which you eluded to), what are you trying to do on the backend?

Comment: I need to use the client to interact with the system for anything I want my scripts to do (eg. get active ticket user is working on in the zendesk system).